# Embed Message (discord)

Tags: discord.js, embed, message

Recently I've been doing a little development but i don't understand why it doesn't works
it makes no error but it still doesn't work idk why if someone can help me it would be really grateful. (just for information my discord.js is a 12.5.3 version)
the script is this:

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('message', async (message) => {
    if (message.content.toLowerCase() === 'ip') {
    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setColor('#000000')
          .setTitle('Région Loxydienne')
          .setAuthor('Rayden')
          .addFields({
            name: '**IP**',
            value: 'DaddyTermi.aternos.me'
          }, {
            name: '**VERSION**',
            value: 'MC 1.17.1'
          }, {
            name: '**IP DYNAMIQUE**',
            value: 'Demande à Tormi'
          })
          .setTimestamp()
          .setImage('https://img.wallpapersafari.com/desktop/1680/1050/6/72/8xbBhw.jpg')
          .setDescription('bon toutou!')
          .setThumbnail('https://imgur.com/gallery/BqUcRTF')

         channel.send(embed);
        }
    })
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't get any errors in console **at all**? Without an error I can only think of adding `;` after `.setThumbnail('https://imgur.com/gallery/BqUcRTF')` like this: `.setThumbnail('https://imgur.com/gallery/BqUcRTF');`

Comment: Have you confirmed your message event emits and the if statement fires? Try some debugging

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you haven't defined channel, you can try to change it to

```
message.channel.send(embed)
```

Or

```
const channel = client.channels.cache.get("channel id")
channel.send(embed)
```

As for no errors, you can try to type
`console.log("test")`
on the next line of
`channel.send(embed)`
to see if it is sent normally

I guess the reason why you didn’t make a mistake is because he did not read your command at all, or was interrupted in the middle, and the above is done to know whether he was successfully executed, or did not read it at all, I think  The possibility of not reading is higher

Answer (score -1):

Since i dont see any channel variable so ig you have not explicitly mentioned any channel to code…so maybe try

message.channel.send(embed);

Comment: Yea, it can be a solution, it's just weird because OP says they don't have any errors in console, if there was no channel variable - they would have at least one

Answer (score -2):

on the channel.send line, change it to:

```
channel.send({embed})
```

Comment: OP is using v12.5.3 and not v13